# How to save an image using PHP and GD

Tags: php, gd

I am created dynamic image using php and gd library as follows,

```
imagecopy ($iOut,$imgBuf[0],$left,$top,0,0,imagesx($imgBuf[0]),imagesy($imgBuf[0]));
imagedestroy ($imgBuf[0]);


ob_start();
    imagepng($iOut);
    printf('<img src="data:image/png;base64,%s"/>', base64_encode(ob_get_clean()));
```

How can I save this image to my local directory for further use. Any help please

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Look at the `imagepng` documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php

You can pass in a second parameter to the function as

```
bool imagepng ( resource $image [, string $filename [, int $quality [, int $filters ]]] )
```

So you can do

```
imagepng($iOut, $filename_to_save_to);
```

then you can simply display the image in the browser as

```
echo '<img src="' . $public_visible_path_to_saved_file . '"/>';
```

For this to work, i would choose the `$filename_to_save_to` as a file in a subdirectory of your web root. E.g.

if your web root is `/var/www` i would choose `/var/www/uploaded_images/filename.png` then you can simply display it by specifying the `$public_visible_path_to_saved_file` as `uploaded_images/filename.png`

Comment: $iOut not defined here nor in the question.

Answer (score 6):

This will work if you want to save the files to your server:

```
ob_start();
imagepng($iOut);
$data = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents('/my/file.png',$data);
```

Answer (score -1):

function render image with php GD

```
   function render_image_page() {

    header ('Content-type: image/png');

    $im = @imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20) or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');
    $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
    imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5, 'A Simple Text String', $text_color);
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);exit;

}
```